# titanium android push notification callback listener

Tags: android, ios, notifications, titanium

I am having a problem. I have looked through the tutorial and had no problems setting up push notifications on android and ios using titanium acs cloudPush.

In the tutorial all the code and functions are placed in app.js. My problem is I want to add push notifications into a more complex app which has a tabGroup and so on. No matter where I place the eventlistener for the notifications it is not being triggered and the app will crash when I try to send a notification to it.

Has anyone implemented push notifications in a more complex app than a single app.js and could  you show where I should put the event listener for my push notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was only on the Android version of the app. I was using the newest Titanium SDK but my version of Titanium CLI was not up to date, updating that finally got my notifications  working on Android again